# How do i filter a row based on any column data with single textbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, ngtable

I am using [`ng-table`](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/).

I tried to use filter given in the [example](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/4), but for filtering each column i need to have separate textbox.

But what i tying to achieve is, One textbox to search any row based on any column data.

How can i achieve this ?

Just like `jquery datatable` search box.

Comment: did you try working with custom filters example?

Comment: @charlietfl ya i tried, custom filters also filtering based on single column

Comment: I don't know this table system...but looking at example 14 External data control. Looks fairly straightforward to create a watch on data set and change it yourself. Keep a copy of original data and use it to reset when user is done filtering

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. As you suggested, using example 14.. i done it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how i did

**Html**

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchUser">

    <table ng-table="tableParams">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        ...
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**Script**

```
        var usersData = []; // initial data

        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,           
            count: 7
        }, {
        counts : [7,14,21,28],          
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            var searchedData = searchData();
            params.total(searchedData.length);
            $scope.users = searchedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            $defer.resolve($scope.users);                           
        },
        $scope: { $data: {} }
    });


$scope.$watch("searchUser", function () {
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
});

var searchData = function(){
    if($scope.searchUser)
       return $filter('filter')(usersData,$scope.searchUser);
    return usersData;
}
```

Remaining default `ngtable` configuration.

Comment: You might consider prevent reload of table on first load by wrapping the reload inside this `this.last !== undefined` , a complete example : `$scope.$watch("searchUser", function () {
  if (this.last !== undefined) {
   $scope.tableParams.reload();
  }
 });`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the original question, if you are loading up all your data initially, then it's pretty easy.  I used this http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-api for reference and then added typeahead filtering with ng-change.

View:

```
<form name="awesomeForm" novalidate>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search term" name="searchTerm" ng-model="globalSearchTerm" ng-change="applyGlobalSearch(globalSearchTerm)" required />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
</form>
```

In your controller (after you load up the data in your table):

```
$scope.applyGlobalSearch = function(term) {
    $scope.tableParams.filter({ $: term });
}
```